# CollectionProperty avoid duplicate names

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I have a CollectionProperty like this:

```
class RenderGroups(PropertyGroup):
    image = StringProperty(name="Image", description="The image-texture of this group")

class MHFCMeshProps(PropertyGroup):
    render_groups = CollectionProperty(type=RenderGroups,
                                       name="Render Groups")
```

Now I don't want duplicate names in the PropertyGroup but I stumbled when I tried to shadow the internal `name` with a StringProperty. Is there any way the following code:

```
g = obj.testgroup.render_groups.add()
g.name = "Name"
g = obj.testgroup.render_groups.add()
g.name = "Name"
```

would result in two different keys "Name" and "Name.001" for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my idea: Overwrite the attribute setting function of the class. The following code has been created mostly be the OP, based on that idea. I added some minor formatting for better readability:

```
import bpy
import re
from bpy.props import *

unique_names = ['name']

class RenderGroups(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    image = StringProperty(
            name="Image", 
            description="The image-texture of this group")

    def __setattr__(self, name, value): 

        def collection_from_element(self):
            # this gets the collection that the element is in
            path = self.path_from_id()
            match = re.match('(.*)\[\d*\]', path)
            parent = self.id_data
            try:
                coll_path = match.group(1)
            except AttributeError:
                raise TypeError("Propery not element in a collection.") 
            else:
                return parent.path_resolve(coll_path)

        def new_val(stem, nbr):
            # simply for formatting
            return '{st}.{nbr:03d}'.format(st=stem, nbr=nbr)

        # =====================================================

        if name not in unique_names:
            # don't want to handle
            self[name] = value
            return
        if value == getattr(self, name):
            # check for assignement of current value
            return

        coll = collection_from_element(self)
        if value not in coll:
            # if value is not in the collection, just assign
            self[name] = value
            return

        # see if value is already in a format like 'name.012'
        match = re.match('(.*)\.(\d{3,})', value)
        if match is None:
            stem, nbr = value, 1
        else:
            stem, nbr = match.groups()

        # check for each value if in collection
        new_value = new_val(stem, nbr)
        while new_value in coll:
            nbr += 1
            new_value = new_val(stem, nbr)
        self[name] = new_value

class MHFCMeshProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    render_groups = CollectionProperty(
            type=RenderGroups,
            name="Render Groups")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(RenderGroups)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MHFCMeshProps)
    bpy.types.Object.testprop = PointerProperty(type=MHFCMeshProps)
```

Now you can do this in the blender python console:

```
obj=bpy.context.object
g=obj.testprop .render_groups.add()
g.name, g.whatever="testme", "keepme"
g.name, g['whatever']
('testme', 'keepme')

g=obj.testprop .render_groups.add()
g.name, g.whatever="testme", "keepme"
g.name, g['whatever']
('testme.001', 'keepme')
```

I think the code example above is now pretty much complete. <s>Although there is still one caveat here.</s> This keeps track of reassigning the current value and always assigns the lowest nbr possible.

Comment: That is a great approach and possibly solves the issue. Will try to think of a solution to the "one caveat" you are talking about because that would feel a bit weird for the user.

Comment: I added a quick check for avoiding to reassign the same value twice. A better solution could be to store the list of appended numbers (001, 002, ...) in the value_dict instead of only the counter (id). Then when assigning a new value, the old value's appended number could be removed from the value_dict, then the new value's number can be calculated by iterating the value_dict and search for the first "free" entry. Do you want me to change the example code to show the idea in action ?

Comment: Rewritten the script myself based on your idea with `__setattr__()`. Works fine the way it is, maybe you can find a way to improve or speed it up

Comment: i am not sure if this is really working correct. create a testprop and name it g.name="testme", then create another testprops and name it g.name="testme" the second testprop is now named "testme.001" as expected. now rename the second testprop again g.name="testme"   now the name is changed to "testme.002" while i expected it to remain "testme.001". BTW i believe there is a bug in one of the regular expressions. Around line 40: Shouldn't it belike this ?  match = re.match('(.*)\.(\d{3,})', value)

Comment: oops, i fixed the bug as well and made some minor changes to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with the api I think. I would suggest to implement your own function:

```
#collection:    collection, where you want to add a new entry
#name:          the 'original' name, will maybe modified
def add_new(collection, name): #or add_unique is maybe better
    #check if name allready exists in the given collection
    #if not add it directly
    if name in collection:
        try:
            #check if the name has allready a number
            #if not this will produce an error and except will be executed
            if name[-4:-3] == '.': #check for a point
                int(name[-3:])
                #cut out the 'original' name
                #([:-4] remove last 4 chars)
                name = name[:-4]
        except:
            #if its not an integer, do nothing
            pass

        i = 1
        #generate three chars with '0' ('{:0>3}') and
        #replace it with the next number (.format)
        #until a free number is found
        while (name + '.{:0>3}'.format(str(i))) in collection:
            #otherwise continue counting
            i += 1
        #add number to name
        name = name + '.{:0>3}'.format(str(i))
    #finally add item
    itm = collection.add()
    # ... and assign name
    itm.name = name
    #return that item
    return itm
```

Then you can use this in your code:

```
g = add_new(obj.testgroup.render_groups, "Name")
#->g.name= "Name"

g = add_new(obj.testgroup.render_groups, "Name")
#->g.name= "Name.001"

g = add_new(obj.testgroup.render_groups, "Name.001")
#->g.name= "Name.002" not "Name.001.001"
```

Comment: hm, is there a way I don't have to call this function every time I want to add an object, though? As a member of a group of programmers they may forget to use this.

Comment: maybe, but thats beyond my capabilities

Comment: EDIT: added a line to check for a point before the number