# Double-Click-rename on a list item does not call __setattr__

Tags: python, scripting

I have a custom list to show some Groups to the user like this:

```
class RenderGroups(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    image = StringProperty(
            name="Image",
            description="The image-texture of this group")

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        _name = "name"
        print("Hi", attr == _name)
        super().__setattr__(attr, new_value)

class RenderGroupUIList(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            row = layout.row()
            if not item:
                row.label(text="", translate=False, icon_value=icon)
                return
            row.prop(item, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)
            if item.image not in bpy.data.images:
                row.label(icon="ERROR")
        # 'GRID' layout type should be as compact as possible (typically a single icon!).
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="", icon_value=icon)
```

The problem now is the following:

- When I access an element of the list (`C.object.test_list`) with `C.object.test_list[0].name = "New name"` it prints `"Hi"`
- When I set the name of an element of the list via double clicking on the item in the Pane I show the list in, the Info-Header tells me `bpy.context.object.test_list[1].name = "New Name"` but "Hi" never shows up in the console (Yes, the System Console in this context)

EDIT: closely connected to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15122). I need to check for updates of `prop.name`, not `prop.image`.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom `__setattr__` method is called if you add or change a collection item via Python (e.g. *Python Console*). It is not called if you change an entry via the UI.

The reason is probably that bpy properties are no regular python objects / properties. If you access it directly via Python, it is handled like a regular Python object. The UI however is handled in Blender's native C code (so are change events in Blender in general), and it obviously disregards custom `__setattr__` handlers.

The proper way to check for property changes is to supply a callback function to the `update` attribute on property registration, or specify a getter and a setter function.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *

def update_cb(self, context):
    print("image =", self.image)

class RenderGroups(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    image = StringProperty(
            name="Image",
            description="The image-texture of this group",
            update=update_cb)


class RenderGroupUIList(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            row = layout.row()
            if not item:
                row.label(text="", translate=False, icon_value=icon)
                return
            row.prop(item, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)
            row.prop(item, "image", text="", emboss=False)
            if item.image not in bpy.data.images:
                row.label(icon="ERROR")
        # 'GRID' layout type should be as compact as possible (typically a single icon!).
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="", icon_value=icon)


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.template_list("RenderGroupUIList", "", context.object, "coll", context.object, "idx")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Object.coll = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.RenderGroups)
    bpy.types.Object.idx = bpy.props.IntProperty()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Object.coll
    del bpy.types.Object.idx


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Be careful with writes to the property inside a callback, there is no protection against infinite loops - you need to handle that yourself.

http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.props.html#get-set-example

Comment: I want to check for updates of `name` as you might already see from `attr == "name"` and I don't see how that is possible with an update function (that's the reason I use `__setattr__` in the first place)

Comment: `update_cb()` is called whenever you change the `image` property in my example, could be any property you register beforehand. Why doesn't that work for you? The fact that `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` comes with a `StringProperty` called `name` doesn't matter, just re-define it in your property group.

Comment: sadly shadowing the `name` property will not override the `name` from PropertyGroup that is used by the collection. Re-defining it-- I guess all of my scripts ... may work, but when someone's iterating the collection they may not get what they expect `name` to do.